# Weird visual result for MLE of normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, python, log-likelihood

I am trying to visualize the log likelihood estimator for normal distribution via python but in vain. I am not sure if its a python issue or formuala issue in the code. Can you kindly have a look?

Letting $\theta_1 = \mu$ and $\theta_2 = \sigma^2$,

$$
L(\theta_1, \theta_2) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^m\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta_2}}\text{exp}\Big[ -\dfrac{(x_i - \theta_1)^2}{2\theta_2}\Big] \\
= \Big(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta_2}}\Big)^{m}\text{exp}\Big[ -\dfrac{  \sum_{i=1}^m(x_i - \theta_1)^2}{2\theta_2}\Big] \\
$$

Taking log on both sides, 
$$
ln(L(\theta_1, \theta_2)) = - \dfrac{m}{2}\Bigg\{ln(2\pi\theta_2)\Bigg\} -  \dfrac{  \sum_{i=1}^m(x_i - \theta_1)^2}{2\theta_2}
$$

**MWE** is [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/parthi2929/a99e6fd4ce9cf7f0d961736d6e425d04?flush_cache=true)

**My *wrong* output:**
[image]

**Expected output:**
[image]

[Reference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms/112547) for expected output (Answer by gregmacfarlane)

Kindly help.

**Context:** My approach and equations are from [this book](https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/677_fr37hij.pdf), page 269, Example 6.4-3.

## Update 1:

As calculus pointed, I updated a correction in MWE, still getting similar wrong output.

## Update 2:

Found the issue almost still there are problems. It was a programmatic one, that I used X and Y alternatively while *shaping* Z values. This was due to wrong hint given [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-create-3d-surface-plot-wih-three-vectors/1257/3) from Plotly, so was intriguing, why they were giving Y first and then X.

**Wrong code:**

`Z = np.array(Z).reshape(len(t2),len(t1))`

**Corrected code:**

`Z = np.array(Z).reshape((len(t1),len(t2)))`

**Corrected output:**
[image]

Matplotlib's plot_surface totally required a different approach and was able to solve that also.

[image]

## Update 3:

Finding the max point in the surface (actually min because its log), gives me correct mean and sigma values, reassuring more the curve is probably correct.
[image]

[Here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/parthi2929/25e66304d083e11d58b0012e68d7460c) is the updated MWE for both figures.

## Problems still existing:

1. I am always having to have equi sized X and Y. If I reduce X's size, Y also gets reduced in the graph.

Comment: Under the root the standard deviation has to be squared. This is the most obvious flaw.

Comment: thank you very much, however, I still get a similar output after updating. I have taken  variance as $\theta_2$. I have updated the question. Kindly check.

Comment: Maybe you should post your question at Cross Validated as well.

Comment: It will be marked as duplicate, thats why I have to choose which could be better